# How do I obtain a list of schemas that an Oracle user has access to

Tags: oracle, ado.net, schema

In Oracle I can grant privileges on my schema to another user so that the other user has access to my schema (and in turn objects in my schema).

How do I programmatically ,using ADO.NET (either MS or Oracle's provider), obtain a list of schemas to which a particular user has access?

Comment: Actually, in Oracle we can only grant privileges on individual objects in a schema, not to the whole schema

Comment: Does this mean the query mentioned below by dpbradley does not return the schemas to which the connected user has access to?

Comment: APC was just clarifying the Oracle grant architecture - there's no concept of granting access to a schema.  You can grant privileges on objects to a schema or a database role, and you can grant roles to schemas or other roles.  So, schema A may own tables X,Y, and Z but only grant SELECT on table X to schema B.  As schema B, if you run the query below you will see schema A in the result set but this doesn't mean that you can see all of schema A's tables.
(Actually the name of the dictionary view is somewhat misleading - it includes privileges on non-table objects as well)

Comment: Thanks for that. It makes things more clear now.

Answer (score 8):

If connected as the user of interest:

```
select distinct table_schema from all_tab_privs;
```