# How do I determine if I a user requires a schema to access a table?

Tags: oracle

An application needs to access various Oracle database. Some databases have tables in Schemas, some don't - there's no control over this.

If a database has a schema in use, the applicable won't work unless the user enters a schema. I'd like it to be able determine via a SQL query if a schema is required to access the tables so the user can be alerted to this.

I'm aware of the question - [How do I obtain a list of schemas that an Oracle user has access to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193063/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-schemas-that-an-oracle-user-has-access-to) - but that only tells me what schema's can be accessed, not if use of the schema is required to access tables.

Is there an SQL query to one of the system tables that can do this with that user's rights?

Note: The application only has login credentials and doesn't know any table details.

Hope that's clear. Thanks.

Comment: All objects in Oracle databases are in schemas. If you're logged in as a different user then you have to qualify access to objects in another schema (i.e. owned by another user) with the schema name. Unless (a) there is a synonym, which can be a private one owned by the user you're logged in as or more likely (I think) in your case a public one, which you can check for in `all_synonyms`; or the current schema has been changed via `alter session` (which can be done in a logon trigger. You can still always qualify with a schema anyway. What scenario are you trying to deal with?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yep sorry. I don't know enough about Oracle to know what I'm asking. :-) - The problem is some users can access their data without specifying a schema and some can't (depends on their database structure). Some are logging in as the data owning user, some not. I'd like to be able to determine when they enter connection credentials whether they will need to enter schema details too or not.

Comment: sounds like you need public synonyms

Comment: @tbone - I think you misunderstand. There is no control over the database or the data structure. They're all different. This is purely from the application side - it needs to be able to accommodate this variety and determine if a "schema" is required for connections. Otherwise it may use a schema where it shouldn't or not be supplied with one where it needs it.

Comment: If the application doesn't know which tables will be accessed (it allows generic queries?), it can't test in advance. Some tables might have public synonyms but others not, so a single test won't help. If they're potentially in different schemas then the `alter session` won't help either. Always prefixing with a schema won't hurt, it's just more typing. The only rough-guess I can think of is to see if the user you log in as owns *any* tables (in `user_tables`); if they don't then they will need a schema unless there are synonyms, if they do then assume they own everything they want to access?

Comment: its not connection specific.  A user could log into an instance and need to use select * from schema.tableA , and also be able to do: select * from tableB.  It depends on who owns these objects and what synonyms exist.  I would highly suggest working with your DBAs to get a clear plan for this application user

Comment: @tbone - I guess this one is a bust then. There are lots of deployments already so its too late to change datastructures to do it "properly". unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPoole - As commented to tbone, it seems what I want to do isn't possible. Some users use schemas, some don't, but they'll do it consistently (otherwise the app won't work I guess). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question is confusing. For most part in Oracle, you can consider LOGIN == USER == SCHEMA. When you login into your database with your user, you are able to see and access all objects in that user's schema. 
Objects in other schemas (on same database server) can be accesed by SCHEMA2.TABLE1 if connected user has privileges to acces table (there are different privileges...). As already stated in some comments, you do not need to prefix table if synonym exists.
 Your user can access even tables on some remote server if exists appropriate database link.